# How to design polymorphic classes with generics

Tags: scala

I try to design api with generic polymorphism

```
trait GameState {
  def doIt(): Unit
}

trait GameMechanics[T <: GameState] {
  def stateHolder: StateHolder[T]
}

abstract class AbsGameMechanics[T <: GameState](sh: StateHolder[T]) extends GameMechanics[T] {
  override def stateHolder: StateHolder[T] = sh
}

class StateHolder[T <: GameState](var state: T) {
  def get: T = state
  def set(_state: T): Unit = state = _state
}
```

So user should extends `GameState` and `AbsGameMechanics`. `GameMechanics` should have specific type of `GameState`, `DominoMechanics`=>`DominoGameState`

User introduce new game:

```
class DominoGameState extends GameState {
  override def doIt(): Unit = println("domino working!")
}

class DominoMechanics(sh: StateHolder[DominoGameState]) extends AbsGameMechanics[DominoGameState](sh)

val domino = new DominoMechanics(new StateHolder[DominoGameState](new DominoGameState))
```

In my system, i should make polymorphic call to state

```
def internal(gm: GameMechanics[GameState]): Unit = {
  gm.stateHolder.get.doIt()
}
```

it's not compiles, and i can't understand what does it mean:

```
internal(domino)
```

> Error:(41, 11) type mismatch;  found   : A$A133.this.DominoMechanics 
>   required: A$A133.this.GameMechanics[A$A133.this.GameState] Note:
>   A$A133.this.DominoStarting <: A$A133.this.GameState (and
>   A$A133.this.DominoMechanics <:
>   A$A133.this.AbsGameMechanics[A$A133.this.DominoStarting]), but trait
>   GameMechanics is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as +T
>   instead. (SLS 4.5) internal(domino)
>            ^

I'm doing something wrong. What?

Comment: Search for "Scala covariance", there are a lot of questions about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `internal` only accepts a `GameMechanics[GameState]`, but you try to pass in a `GameMechanics[DominoStarting]`, which is not a subtype of `GameMechanics[GameState]` because `GameMechanics` is invariant in type `T`. You might want to look up some other questions about invariance and covariance, because there are a lot.

But I think the problem in your code is not necessarily about covariance or invariance. You just shouldn't ask for a `GameMechanics[GameState]`. You already defined `T` as having to be a subtype of `GameState`... What you should do if you accept any kind of `GameMechanics` is this:

```
def internal[S <: GameState](gm: GameMechanics[S]): Unit = {
  gm.stateHolder.get.doIt()
}
```

Or when you don't care about the exact type:

```
def internal(gm: GameMechanics[_ <: GameState]): Unit = {
  gm.stateHolder.get.doIt()
}
```